# Telugu font characters not correctly produced from xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, texlive, fontspec, languages

Anyone have this issue.

This is the following code.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Gautami}
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage{telugu}
    \begin{document}
    చేయి అనగా మానవులు, చింపాంజీలు, కోతులు మరియు లెమూర్లకు గల శరీరభాగమునకు వేళ్లు
    కలబాహ్యంగము. కోలా చేతికి ఎదురెదురుగా వున్న రెండు బొటనవ్రేళ్లు వుంటాయి కాబట్టి దాని శరీరభాగాన్ని
    కూడా చేయి లేక 'పా'లు అంటారు.
    \end{document}
```

This is the output I got.

[image]

But Actual ouput should be

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the `gautami.ttf` from MS:

```
voss@shania:~/tmp> otfinfo -i gautami.ttf 
Family:              Gautami
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Gautami
PostScript name:     Gautami
Version:             Version 1.21
Unique ID:           Gautami Regular
Description:         Gautami is an OpenType font for the Indic script-Telugu. It is based on Unicode, contains TrueType outlines and has been designed for use as a UI font.
Designer:            Raghunath Joshi (Type Director), Omkar Shende
Designer URL:        http://www.ncst.ernet.in/~rkjoshi
Copyright:           © 2001 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Vendor ID:           MS
```

and run `xelatex` with an up-to-date TeXLive 2013 on your example:

[image]